# Validating radiobuttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm using the following to make sure fields aren't empty before they get posted in jquery:

```
if(this.field.value == "") {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field required"));
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   return;
}
```

I have some radio buttons that need yes selected, however it doesn't seem to work if I do say:

```
if(this.radiobutton.value == "no") {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   return;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't want to know if the value is "no" : you want to know if the radio with value "no" is checked or not. Use jQuery('radio#no').is(':checked') instead. See more here : http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html

Comment: What is `this` in context of your code and how its `radiobutton` property is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Assign at your radio buttons an id example "radio_button" and use this for all.

```
if($('#radio_button').is(':not(:checked)'))  {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   return;
}
```

if you have any other fields you can choose to use selectors like this

```
if($('#radio_button [name="example"]').is(':not(:checked)'))  {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   return;
}
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting a single id on multiple elements?

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons have multiple fields. You're better checking that the no button is checked.

eg;

```
if(this.radiobutton.checked) {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
  return;
}
```

Where radiobutton is the radio button with a value of no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to check if any radio is chekced or not if checked then what value does it have if `no` then validate it, Try with this :

```
if($(':radio', this).prop(':checked') || $(':radio:checked', this).val() == "no") {
  jQuery( ".page-error-message" ).remove();
  //jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));
  jQuery(".top").append("field must be yes");
  jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
  return;
}
```

`jQuery(".top").append(jQuery("field must be yes"));` this seems a little bit confusing to me, i think this should be something like:

```
jQuery(".top").append("field must be yes");
```